# Arrow at the bottom for active link in angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-routing, angular4-router

I am making an application in angular 6 and i am using bootstrap navbar for router links,

HTML,

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md bg-theme">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <!-- Toggler/collapsibe Button -->
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapsibleNavbar">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>

        <!-- Navbar links -->
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="collapsibleNavbar">
            <ul class="navbar-nav text-light">
                <li class="nav-item" routerLinkActive="active">
                    <a routerLink="/home" class="nav-link text-capitalize theme-font-size-16" href="#">Dashboard</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item" routerLinkActive="active">
                    <a routerLink="/about" class="nav-link text-capitalize theme-font-size-16" href="#">Template</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item" routerLinkActive="active">
                    <a routerLink="/product" class="nav-link text-capitalize theme-font-size-16" href="#">Product</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>

<div class="active"></div>
```

Here i need to get the active class of the clicked link, say if i click the link `Product`, then that particular link has to be get active and if active class applied then i need to show a arrow at the bottom of active link.

Here i am unable to get the active class of the clicked link rather than i am having for all the three links.

I am very new in angular and hence kindly help me if any basic thing missed in it.

The stackblitz that i have worked,

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hhwx3j?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Note: No jquery is allowed in it.

Comment: You have used routerLink and routerLinkAcitve directive which is looking fine. You just need implement the routing to see this in action.

Comment: your mistake is that you put the routerlinkactive on the LI you cant do it, u need to put it on the <a> to it to work right.

Comment: @SunilSingh, Can you use my code (refer question's stackblitz) and show the difference of active links? Because i am not getting any changes if i click on any link.

Comment: Refer this simple example https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-routerlinkactive-ebsmaz

Comment: @SunilSingh, Thanks this is what i have expected.. If you post as answer i will accept this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have used routerLink and routerLinkActive directive which looks fine. Just include the routing configuration in Module.

example -

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'LinkA', component: AComponent },
  { path: 'LinkB', component: BComponent },
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class RootRoutingModule { }
```

Working demo copy is here https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-routerlinkactive-ebsmaz

Answer (score 1):

You have a built in parameters for activted route.
https://angular.io/api/router/RouterLinkActive
have a look at this.

```
                <li class="nav-item" >
                <a routerLink="/home" routerLinkActive="active" class="nav-link text-capitalize theme-font-size-16" href="#">Dashboard</a> <-- use the routerLinkActive here and not on the li
            </li>
```

Comment: Can you use my code (refer question's stackblitz) and show the difference of active links? Because i am not getting any changes if i click on any link.

Comment: ye look at what i eddited

Answer (score 0):

.ts file

```
let links = ['/home','/product','/sample'];
```

.html file

```html
<li class="nav-item" *ngFor = "let item of links">
                    <a routerLink=item class="nav-link text-capitalize theme-font-size-16" routerLinkActive="highlight">{{item}}</a>
                </li>
```

the component for corresponding home,product.. must be defined in the router module.and give styles for "hightlight" . check this https://angular.io/api/router/RouterLinkActive

Comment: Can you use my code (refer question's stackblitz) and show the difference of active links? Because i am not getting any changes if i click on any link.

Comment: you don't need to use "href" prop in angular...instead of that we use routerLink. and for each value of routerLink , corresponding component should be defined in router module

Comment: https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-difference-between-the-href-and-routerLink hope this link will help..

Comment: you have not imported routes in module.ts

Answer (score 0):

Its pretty simple,for that you should create a class say 'active' and use it inside . 
So your code will look like:

```
<li class="nav-item" >
 <a routerLink="/home" [routerLinkActive]="'active'" class="nav-link text-capitalize theme-font-size-16" href="#">Dashboard</a>
</li>
```

Just create a class name active :

```
.active{
border-bottom : 2px solid #095d82;
transition: ease-in-out 0.7s;
 }
```

Comment: Can you use my code (refer question's stackblitz) and show the difference of active links? Because i am not getting any changes if i click on any link.

Comment: You have not imported routes in app.module.ts

Comment: You have missed lots of steps in your code in stackbiltz .Your app.module.ts is incomplete